# booting to windows using grub

Tags: boot, grub, bootloader

I was dual booting fedora and windows 7 (installed fedora second). After installing ati drivers, the fedora installation completely broke (would hand right after the progress bar). I wanted to reinstall it to another drive to avoid dual booting. Foolishly, I went into windows, and I deleted the fedora partition and resized C: to include it.

Then, I rebooted, and I am presented with command line grub. There's no nice gui that lets me chose the OS in which I want to boot.

From what I understand, I've probably deleted most of grub, and all that's left is the part in the MBR.

Is there a way I can load windows from this command line?
Even better, is there a way I can eliminate grub, and make it so windows uses all the disk and just boots like it used to when it was alone in the disk?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your install disk. Choose the Repair my Installation (or similar, don't remember exactly_ option near the bottom and then choose Repair Startup-esque option. If that doesn't work, consult the rest of [this guide](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/how-to-reinstall-windows-7-boot-loader/).